# Having error in mysql query when using GROUP_CONCAT() with WHERE clause in nodejs code

Tags: mysql, node.js

This is my code for mysql query string:

let queryString = `SELECT table1.*, group_concat(documents.url) as documentsUrl FROM table1 LEFT JOIN documents ON table1.Id = documents.table1_fk group by table1.Id`;

```
    if (payload.searchString) {
        queryString += ` WHERE firstName LIKE '%${payload.searchString}%' OR lastName LIKE '%${payload.searchString}%'`;
    }
    if (payload.sortColumn) {
        queryString += ` ORDER BY ${payload.sortColumn} ${payload.sortOrder}`;
    }
    if (payload.page) {
        queryString += ` LIMIT ${offset}, ${payload.limit}`;
    }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

> GROUP BY

clause of the SELECT statement should be after the

> WHERE

clause

Comment: Working Fine. Thanks